# Library for electrical network simulation

Tags: c++, python, ruby, simulation

I'm searching for a free and open source library for electrical network simulation.

In (per preference order): [Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29), [Ruby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_%28programming_language%29), [JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript), [PHP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP), [C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B) (with [Qt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_%28software%29), if it exist) or [Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) (ahah).

Is there one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.thedigitalmachine.net/eispice.html

Comment: Thanks, so it's "Circuit", not "electrical networkd" for search (i'm not english). It's build in C and with Python. I will test it :) .

Comment: The link is (effectively) broken: *"This domain may be for sale."*